# Time Series Data: Unequal Sample sizes

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, aggregation, intervention-analysis

I have a dataset which consists of *daily observations* over a 3 month period for different variables. The data are aggregated so I do not have access to user level data.

The problem is that the **number of users** is not the same every day. I want to conduct an intervention analysis using the *ARIMA* model. How could I overcome this issue of unequal daily users? Or is it a limitation I cannot avoid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before I respond, what sort of outcome are you trying to forecast?

Comment: I want to conduct an intervention analysis on a past dataset of a video game. My goal is to predict the values of certain metrics before the introduction of an intervention in the game and then compare them with the actual values. That way I can estimate the effect of the event that happened.